# Sending binary file data through sockets

Tags: tcp, serversocket

I am trying to write a socket program in C using TCP which sends binary file data from server to client, but I don't know how to do it.

In other words, I need to download a binary file from a server to client.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For sockets there is no difference *what* data is inside the packet. It's called *payload* in terms of networking and its structure, format is only important to the applications that send/receive it. So your question of "sending binary data through sockets" transforms into "how to send data through sockets" which was answered multiple times in SO and there are plenty of tutorials all over the internet. Also you did not mention what platform you are using, so start [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) for Linux and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows or simply google around for *socket programming*.